# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentUser' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, authentication

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd44j.png)

[service.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYsa7.png)

When I run localhost in console I have error

> bundle.js:7541 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentUser'
>   of undefined(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:7541invoke @
>   bundle.js:12268(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:12076forEach @
>   bundle.js:7880createInjector @ bundle.js:12076doBootstrap @
>   bundle.js:9310bootstrap @ bundle.js:9331angularInit @
>   bundle.js:9216(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:39027j @
>   jquery.js:3047fireWith @ jquery.js:3159ready @ jquery.js:3365I @
>   jquery.js:3380

Please help (I think I forgot something)

Comment: It's quite expectedly error. Services in Angular are lazy instantiated components. I didnt noticed where are you using `AuthenticationService`

Answer (score 0):

Inside app.js you have $window.localStorage.currentUser.

$window.localStorage is undefined and so you get the error that can't find currentUser of undefined.

change to: if ($window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.currentUser)